# Bootstrap 3: Collapse on hover e fixa no click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Gostaria de saber como fazer para que o Collapse do Bootstrap 3 abra no hover e caso seja clicado ele fique fixo (Não feche) e só feche caso outro collapse seja clicado (E este outro collapse abra).

Com o seguinte código eu consegui fazer com que ele abra no hover, mas nao consigo fixa-lo no click.

```
// Classe .menu-header abraça todo o collapse para que ele nao feche ao retirar o hover do botão.
$('.menu-header').hover(function () { 
    $('#administrativoCollapse').toggleClass('in');
});
```

Comment: Não entendi direito tua pergunta, o collapse padrão já deixa a div que vai aparecer fixa, você quer que no hover ela apareça e depois feche o no onClick fique fixa?

Comment: Isso, o padrão do collapse é no primeiro click ele abre e no segundo ele fecha, eu gostaria que ele abra/feche no hover e caso o usuário de um click ele se mantenha aberto mesmo se o ponteiro nao estiver mais em hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o seguinte código para que quando clicar, além de você setar a classe para deixar ele aberto, você remove o evento de hover.

```
$('.menu-header').click(function () { 
    $('#administrativoCollapse').toggleClass('in');
    $('#menu-header').off('hover');
});
```